# Facebook Ads - after setting campaign it is not showing in ad manager

Tags: php, advertising, facebook

#### Description:

I bought new campaign in facebook ads service. The type of it is Website Conversions. I implemented pixel (registering) sucessfully, redeemed created list of ads and inserted new card data.

In ads manager everything seems alright, pixel is set to active, billing settings are correct but when I click "Campaigns and adverts" I dont see my new campaign. Also I didn't get any e-mail notification so I have no idea is it working or not.

#### Problem to solve

Why I don't see newly created campaign? I suppose Facebook should at least inform me if everything is alright. Please tell me then, is that normal behaviour or something went wrong and I should redeem campaing once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After waiting about 8 hours, looking for contact with facebook (with no result.. am I blind?) I took the risky way.

I redeemed my ad campaign once more, this time it appeared in "Campaigns & Adverts" properly. I have no idea why it didn't worked first time.. It could be some kind of bug, but I cannot approve this with any evidences.

#### Edit:

That really was bug, I created 6 ads but in campaign appear to be 12 but this is not the only problem. My ad account has been blocked (suspicious activity). Probably this is their mistake how there can be 12 from 6 right? And now I stuck to clarify the matter.